# JBPM6 WAR not Deploying on Jboss EAP 6.3.0 and EAP 6.2.0

Tags: deployment, drools, jbpm, jboss-eap-6

I am unable to deploy the JBPM6 full-installer generated war file in to Jboss-EAP-6.3.0 and EAp-6.2.0.

**Problem Statement**

Whenever I deploy the generated WAR into Jboss-EAP-6.3.0 server, I get the following error. I have generated the war file from the **jbpm-6.1.0.Final-installer-full.zip**.

I have taken the WAR from

```
      <i>jbpm-installer\lib\jbpm-console-6.1.0.Final </i>
```

and also tried with the

```
      <i> jbpm-installer\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\standalone\deployments\jbpm-console.war </i>
```

**ERROR**

*17:35:19,907 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.servi
    ce.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".STRUCTURE: JBAS018733: **Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "jbpm-console.war"**
            at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018774: Error loading jboss-all.xml from D:\DevelopmentWorks\A - JBPM CLEAN\jboss-eap-6.3\standalo
    ne\tmp\vfs\temp\tempf6aa08ac4728b487\content-ab7fc8043b0c6a18\META-INF\jboss-all.xml
            at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.jbossallxml.JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.parse(JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.java:153) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Fina
    l-redhat-19]
            at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.jbossallxml.JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.parse(JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.java:128) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Fina
    l-redhat-19]
            at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.jbossallxml.JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.deploy(JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.java:96) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Fina
    l-redhat-19]
            at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
            ... 5 more
    Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[18,3]
    Message: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:weld:1.0}weld'
            at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:108)
            at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.handleAny(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:69)
            at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.jbossallxml.JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor$Parser.parseJBossElement(JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.java:203) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redha
    t-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
            at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.jbossallxml.JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor$Parser.readElement(JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.java:192) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.j
    ar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
            at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.jbossallxml.JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor$Parser.readElement(JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.java:176) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.j
    ar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
            at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110)
            at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69)
            at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.jbossallxml.JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.parse(JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.java:148) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Fina
    l-redhat-19]
            ... 8 more*

```
17:35:19,937 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "jbpm-console.war" was rolled back with the following failure message
:
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".STRUCTURE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.
war\".STRUCTURE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"jbpm-console.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018774: Error loading jboss-all.xml from D:\\DevelopmentWorks\\A - JBPM CLEAN\\jboss-eap-6.3\\
standalone\\tmp\\vfs\\temp\\tempf6aa08ac4728b487\\content-ab7fc8043b0c6a18\\META-INF\\jboss-all.xml
    Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[18,3]
**Message: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:weld:1.0}weld'"}}**
17:35:19,944 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment jbpm-console.war (runtime-name: jbpm-console.war) in 6ms
17:35:19,955 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (HttpManagementService-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".STRUCTURE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the war is prepared for wildfly (there are some specific dependencies that needs to be added to it to work), so you need to get the EAP distribution, or you can build that from the source code.

If you clone and build this repository: https://github.com/droolsjbpm/kie-wb-distributions/ (most specifically the kie-wb app) and look inside the kie-wb/kie-wb-distribution-wars, you will find the EAP ready war.

Or you can download the already built WAR for EAP including SNAPSHOTS and CR release from Nexus: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/index.html#nexus-search;gav~org.kie~kie-wb-distribution-wars~~~~kw,versionexpand

(look at the link in the right most column for EAP 6_4 or 6_3 depending the version)